# Expo app crashes on Android on hot reload and in production

Tags: android, react-native, expo, crash, expo-dev-client

We are having a problem with our Expo dev client app. Problem is, when we hot reload the app, app crashes. Those crashes happen randomly (sometimes after 2nd hot reload, sometimes after 8th).
The error is not only when hot reloading, it happens in production aswell.

I have ran the code from android studio and crash says this:
[Native Crash logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEzW8.png)

When i hot reload and app DOES NOT crashes, i get this logs which are fine:
[Good Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olNf4.png)

I dont have any error show in metro console, app just closes.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "buebue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android --device",
    "ios": "expo run:ios --device",
     ...
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "promise": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/ngrok": "^2.5.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@freakycoder/react-native-bounceable": "^1.0.3",
    "@giphy/js-fetch-api": "^4.9.0",
    "@giphy/js-types": "^4.4.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.5.0",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@sentry/react-native": "5.5.0",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.6.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.5",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "double-click-react-native": "^0.1.8",
    "expo": "49.0.18",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "4.1.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-fast-image": "^1.1.3",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.4",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-print": "~12.4.2",
    "expo-random": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.17",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "htmlparser2": "^9.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "^47.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "missing-dimension-strategy-expo-config-plugin": "^0.0.5",
    "papaparse": "5.4.1",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-circular-progress-indicator": "^4.4.2",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-dashed-line": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-fit-image": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-iap": "^12.10.7",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-markdown-display": "^7.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-paper-dates": "^0.18.1",
    "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-root-siblings": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "sentry-expo": "~7.0.0",
    "truncate-html": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "dotenv-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "11.1.4",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Did someone encounter this problem?